# Transitivity of parallel lines

Tags: geometry

I cam across a question (in my textbook) about proofs with parallel lines.  The question is: **Prove that the property that || is transitive implies that for any point P and line l, there is at the most 1 line through P that is parallel to the line l.**

In other words the question is asking me to prove that **(P is on *q* & P is on *s* & *l*||*q* & *l*||*s*) --> *q* = *s***, using the transitive property.

I know that the transitivity property tells me that **l||m & m||n --> n||l**, but I am not sure how to do this proof.

Any hints or solutions would be much appreciated!! :)

Thank you in advance

Comment: The notation in your second paragraph is messed up.  On the left side, you have q,s,n but on the right side you have m and n.  Once you correct this, you should be able to see the solution.

Comment: @Ted After correcting it, I can see that q || s, but I can't think of the next step

Comment: q||s, but they both go through P, so ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say it is not true.

take 2 lines a and b with p on them, both parallel to l. than a||l and b||l, because of symmetry of ||, l||b. because of transitivity a||b. a||b and p on both a and b, a=b.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show that the transitivity of parallelism is equivalent to the Playfair's Axiom.  It's explained perfectly here:

http://www.mathteacherctk.com/blog/2011/10/is-parallelism-an-equivalence-relation/

Michael